# NSDateFormatter transition to NSString error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, foundation

here is the code

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSString * dateNow = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

and the debugger shows

[image]

and why the number of the year is 2016?

Comment: Use [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` in your `NSDateFormatter` as

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
---------------------------^^^^
```

> why the number of the year is 2016?

The **reason** being:

The "YYYY" is a week-based calendar year.

The "yyyy" is an ordinary calendar year.

Answer (score 2):

change the setdateformatter line as below,

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Year 2016 is because current week (27-Dec-2015) to (02-Jan-2016) is the 1st week of 2016 based on weekly calendar year as specified by format YYYY. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date